# How to control C++ DLL exported functions "easily"

Tags: c++, function, dll, export

Say I have a bunch of functions exported in a C++ DLL. 
A customer asks for some code implementation which uses only some of the functions in the DLL.
I'd like to give the customer a DLL with the relevant functions only (because full DLL is too big, I dont want to send code he doesnt need to see, etc..).

Is there any way to export only part of the functions easily (e.g. without adding/removing "__declspec dllexport" declarations everytime)?
Perhaps "hide" function from full DLL or re-compile slimmer DLL (but control which functions included in a clean way).

Thanks!

Comment: Conditional compilation maybe? Not quite sure what you want.

Comment: maybe. I want to find an easy way to have a code repository of functions that can be used "dynamically" to create custom DLLs (per client needs).

Comment: Convert your existing DLL into a static library.  Make a shim/stub DLL project that exports only the necessary functions (for this client) and link with the library.

Comment: well, found some solution. Given that the functions are split to different files (.h/.cpp), then in VS I can simply set unwanted .cpp to "Exclude from Build == yes".  Seem to do the job. I wonder if there's some other automatic trick out there..